# Enforcing field type using Mongoid 3

Tags: mongoid, mongoid3

I'm upgrading from Mongoid 2.  I have the following model:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :names, type: Array
end
```

The following used to raise an exception:

```
p = Person.new
p.names = 'stuff'
```

Now under Mongoid 3, no exception is raised, it silently accepts.

How can I enforce array type?

Comment: Maybe try adding a validator to make sure the class of names is Array?

Comment: Yes, was hoping there was some kind of hidden option I could pass into field